# Find MethodInvocation method bindings in JDT ASTVisitor

Tags: eclipse-jdt

I have a java file which uses java.sql.Statement.execute as below.

```
public class Dummy
{
    public void execute(String q) throws SQLException
    {
        ...
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ...
        stmt.execute(q);
        ...
    }
}
```

My use case is I want to identify what are all the classes and their method names which use "Statement.execute(String)" using JDT ASTVisitor. Is this possible?

I found below entry using eclipse ASTView plugin.

> method binding: Statement.execute(String)

How can I get this method binding value in my ASTVisitor.

I tried this.

```
@Override
public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node)
{
    IMethodBinding iMethod = (IMethodBinding) node.resolveMethodBinding();
    if(iMethod != null)
    System.out.println("Binding "+iMethod.getName());
    return super.visit(node);
}
```

but node.resolveMethodBinding() always returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... i want to identify what are all the classes and its method names which using "Statement.execute(String)"

This sounds like a job for the [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine`](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/package-summary.html?cp=3_1_0_23), which will produce the results much faster than traversing all your source files using a visitor.

> ... node.resolveMethodBinding() always returns null

This depends on how you obtained the AST. See, e.g., [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.setResolveBindings(boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html#setResolveBindings-boolean-)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Is it possible to use org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine functionality outside eclipse as a standalone java application? Currently i have constructed ASTNode from my standalone application using ASTParser.

Comment: The search engine relies on an index of your projects. While it is possible to create that index offline, I'm not sure if it's worth it for standalone application - search engine may pull in more requirements. OTOH, why not morph your tool into an Eclipse plugin so it can leverage all the coolness of the platform, integrate in the UI etc.? If that's not an option, asking the ASTParser to resolve bindings should be the quickest solution for your task.

Comment: @ParthiP did you try `ASTParser.setResolveBindings(true)`? If so, did it help?

Comment: ASTParser.setResolveBindings(true) solved my problem.